# CreateFileMapping - параметры dwMaximumSizeHigh

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста по функции CreateFileMapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga

Там есть два параметра:

> **[in] dwMaximumSizeHigh**
>
> Параметр DWORD старшего разряда максимального размера объекта
> сопоставления файлов.
>
> **[in] dwMaximumSizeLow**
>
> Младший DWORD максимального размера объекта сопоставления файлов.
>
> Если этот параметр и dwMaximumSizeHigh равны 0 (нулю), максимальный
> размер объекта сопоставления файлов равен текущему размеру файла,
> который идентифицирует hFile .
>
> Попытка сопоставить файл длиной 0 (ноль) завершается с ошибкой с кодом
> ERROR_FILE_INVALID . Приложения должны проверять файлы длиной 0 (ноль)
> и отклонять эти файлы.

У меня CreateFileMapping создается с параметром INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Я ни как не могу понять, что они значат.

Что еще за младший DWORD - максимального размера объекта сопоставления файлов ?

Я должен придумать число " максимального размера объекта сопоставления файлов" и указать младшие два байта ??

Comment: ¿Что тут непонятного? Передается максимальный размер объекта сопоставления. Младшие четыре байта в одном аргументе и старшие четыре - в другом. Такие заковырки остались в WinAPI со времен, когда еще не было поддержки 64 битных целых чисел в языке.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! То есть я должен условно представить размер данных которые я хочу передавать в условно 8 битной переменной и указать первые 4 байта это число и вторые 4 байта это числа в 10-ом виде ?

Comment: Нет, прочитайте про то как отделить младшие байты из 64 битного числа от старших

Comment: @ori, ну разве в 64 битном числе - первые 4 байта не будут младшими, а второе 4 байта - старшими ?